# Quantile plot for multiple groups before and after treatment effect

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a question on how to generate a comparative 95% confidence interval a round a median easily in excel. I have seven columns of data, representing 7 different users. I also have a column as an indicator variable (1 or 0). I want to compare the 2.5%,50%, and 97.5% quarantines for each column based on whether or not the indicator variable is a 1 or 0.

So essentially I want a side by side comparison for each User before a treatment effect and after the treatment effect. So two quantile plots per user, so 14 of these in total with users on the x axis and the numbers on the Y. How do i easily go about this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about the data source? Based on your description, not easy to create a chart of your requirement.